# How do you write a good reaserch paper title?

Tags: research-process, science, biology

I'm doing a paper on the medicinal properties of everyday plants but my prof. says that its too broad and I need to narrow it down. I want to start by figuring out a better title that is more specified to the research. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The two obvious ways are (a) think about the problem to be solved (main question to be answered) and (b) think about the main result. Either of those can lead to a title, with (b) probably better.

A combination of the two, if short enough might be even better.